# Server side VS Client side rendered template performance?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom

Is there any **noticable** performance difference between:

Rendering template completely on the server side and just delivering it as a static html to the client.

**VS**

Rendering template on the client using frameworks like AngularJS which loads data via ajax call.

A sample use case can be loading list of 100 comments for a blog. (I'm not sure if this is the best use case for this question). This can be done in Angular by fetching JSON data and then passing it to the controller which then renders the view with data-binding. For a static page, this can be rendered completely on the server and served directly on the client.

I'm considering following things to consider performance difference:

1. Time taken to insert new nodes on the DOM tree. (in case of Angular)
2. Time taken to apply css styles.
3. Please add anything else I've missed out.

Comment: I'd say the main differences between the two approaches are that all content are available to the person browsing the page when rendering at server-side, but the page takes longer to load VS faster loading time with AngularJS approach, but wait a few secs for content fetched with ajax. The time it takes for angular to render the data i'd say is neglectable. Once the data is loaded though, AngularJS will probably be faster to e.g. get new data, since you don't have to refresh the whole page etc. Applying CSS is done on client-side either way?

Comment: Also, depending on how many users are using your site, you might gain some performance by placing rendering in the client, to take some load off your servers. And of course, the perfomance users get with the client-side approach is more dependent on the computer they have.

Comment: If you are building a regular site for regular users, modern machines are generally pretty powerful, and rendering 100 comments is fine. However if your target user is atypical, for example if you expect your target users to have old machines and old browsers, you may want server side rendering to ensure good performance.

Comment: @Arg0n please add in your comment as an Answer

Comment: @igor yes I'm assuming users with modern computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the main differences between the two approaches are:

(**Server-side rendering**)
All content are available to the person browsing the page when rendering at server-side, but the page takes longer to load

(**Angular / Client-side rendering**)
Faster initial loading time of the page, but wait a few secs for content fetched with ajax.

The time it takes for angular to render the data i'd say is neglectable. Once the data is loaded though, AngularJS will probably be faster to e.g. get new data, since you don't have to refresh the whole page etc.

Applying CSS is done on client-side either way